# vbScript function returns a value that cannot be converted to an XSL data type

Tags: xml, function, xslt, vbscript, msxsl

I get the below error when I try to display XML data using XSL. The VBScript Function throws this error:

Function "MyFuctionName" returns a value that cannot be converted to an XSL data type.
What could be the cause.
Snapshot of Code below:
1.XML

```
        <Client>
             <ClientID>34987886</ClientID>
               <LnkSeqNo>1</LnkSeqNo>
        </Client>
```

2.XSL code,function.

```
    Dim ClientID 

    function SetClientID(ID)
        ClientID = ID
    end function
```

...

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Object/Client">
           <xsl:if test="LnkSeqNo[. = '1' or . = '57']"> 
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="vbs:SetClientID(string(ClientID))"/>
..
          </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function does not return any value at all, and `xsl:value` is expecting a value.  If you want to just execute the function and not output anything, you could probably have the function return an empty string, but I would suggest reconsidering your approach. It's not generally good practice to use functions with side effects in XSLT, and runs counter to the principles of XSLT.

Comment: Ok cool thanx @JLRishe,How does my Function must look like to return a value or an empty string?

Comment: I figured it out. I set my Function to null to return a null value. like this:

function SetClientID(ID)
        ***SetClientID=""***
        ClientID = ID
end function


Thanks a lot @JLRishe